# How to add taxonomy term under the thumbnail on woocommerce product page

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, taxonomy

I have created a taxonomy names "status" for woocommerce product post type, I want to display the terms under the thumbnail on the main products page. I'd appreciate if anyone can help me to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have override template system in woocommerce and apply my script in loop --> price.php. the script goes above the price tag.